# Where is this house and mountains in Colorado, USA?

Tags: identify-this, colorado

I stumbled on this at [r/houseporn](https://redd.it/akhhzk).

1. Can I rent this house for a day or two?
2. Where is it?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This appears to be a house in Aspen, Colorado architected by Charles Cunniffe Architects, see [here](https://www.cunniffe.com/projects/aspen-glam/). On that page you can see a full gallery of the house with other angles of the mountains. It appears to be a private residence that does not appear to be rentable.